# Windows 10 - not recognising headphones

Tags: laptop, audio, windows-10

I recently updated to windows 10 and have now noticed that when I place my headphones into the jack my laptop still plays sound on the speakers, I had this problem back when I updated to windows 8 (I believe) but can't for the life of me remember how I solved the issue.

Comment: What headphone is it?  Go to headphone manufacturer and download updated software?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the drivers.

In my case I solved this problem on my Alienware after upgrading to Windows 10 by going to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Creative\Sound Blaster Recon3Di\Drivers` and running `setup.exe`.